# How to convert a Delegate to a string of code?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, delegates

I'm trying to recover the code of a delegate, by converting it to a string, with no success so far ):

Take this piece of code for example:

```
Delegate del = new Delegate()
del = (MethodInvoker) delegate { MessageBox.Show("hello from delegate") };
```

I wanna know if there is any operation I can perform on `del` to retrieve a string representing its C# code.

I Guess what i'm looking for is Serialization, but i'm not sure...
I've tried the Delegate.ToString() but it doesnt retur what i want...

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this?  There may be a better/easier way to accomplish your goals.

Comment: there is nothing included in the the .net framework that does what you want here. The closest thing is reflection

Comment: Also, why do you set `del` to `new Delegate()` only to replace that value on the next line?

Comment: What's the reason why you would convert the delegate to a string?

Comment: Just `new Delegate()` wouldn't work. `Delegate` doesn't have  public parameterless constructor.

Comment: If what you want is to serialize code, you may consider using [System.Activities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd485307.aspx) with the provided [Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.aspx), [Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.expressions.aspx) or even your own activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option.

The delegate can be seen as yet another method. The compiler compiles this down to some MSIL instructions. At that point you lost the original C# source in your assembly and hence, therefore lost the possibility of showing the original C# code itself. (There are some reverse engineering options but those are way to complex).

You can use expressions to setup a representation of what you want  and let the runtime boil it down to whatever is required by then (C#, MSIL, SQL etc). example:

```
Expression<Action> expr = () => MessageBox.Show("test");

Console.WriteLine(expr.ToString()); 
// () => Show("test")
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible in general.

If you accept an `Expression<TDelegate>` (an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)) instead of an ordinary delegate, you can call `ToString()` to get a string representation.
However, the compiler can only convert lambda expressions (not blocks) to expression trees.

Comment: Can you provide me an example of usage?

Comment: `Expression<Func<int, bool>> lambda = num => num < 5;`

Comment: @SLaks How to convert the string back to lambda expression?

Comment: Can I convert a Delegate to a Expression?

Comment: @ojlovecd: That's not possible; the string may refer to variables from a closure.  If it doesn't, you'd need a parser; Roslyn would help.

Comment: @user1038863: That's fundamentally impossible.

Comment: Hmmm, can I retrive IL code from a delegate? Using some ildasm wrapper or anything like that

Comment: @Salvia: Call `GetMethodBody()`.  Note that a delegate can point to multiple methods.